# How to attain UI like this with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

[image: How to attain that two Arcs?]

I've created an Arc with canvas like this:

```
      Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(255.dp), onDraw = {
        rotate(300f) {
            drawArc(
                color = primary,
                startAngle = 0f,
                sweepAngle = 180f,
                useCenter = false,
                style = Stroke(width = 8f)
            )
        }
    })
```

But, that canvas composable draws in a square shape so that I can't make the edges of arc to touch border of the screen.

[image: how to make the arc edges touch top and left border of the screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `topLeft = Offset(x, y)` in the `drawArc` function with negative values for `x` and `y` if necessary to translate it where you need it.